Максимальный размер блока памяти calloc/malloc c++
В последнее время я работаю с большими размерами динамических массивов в проекте, и в один момент у меня начала вылазить ошибка повреждения кучи, причем она происходила в библиотеке ntdll.dll, что для меня показалось очень странно, 100% нет выхода за рамки выделенного блока, я этот проверял несколько раз. Я стал грешить на то, что может у calloc есть лимит выделения, но в интернете особо не нашел точных данных, строка выделения памяти в программе выглядит примерно так:
while (array == NULL) array = (byte*)calloc(size_t(1000 * 1000), sizeof(byte*));
100% для выделения достаточно оперативной памяти. Вот кстати тот скрин с ошибкой


пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Это значит, что нужно приводить полный код, пожалуйста. По этому фрагменту ничего внятного сказать сложно

Ксатии, sizeof(byte*) и sizeof(byte) дадут разное значение, уверены, что вам нужен первый вариант?

И c byte*, и с byte падает в ошибку

«нет выхода за рамки выделенного блока» — не верю

Можешь не верить, в программе буквально размер массива и кол-во циклов зависит от 1 переменной и фактический размер массива и кол-во циклов - 1 выражение
while (array== NULL) array= (byte*)calloc(size_t(var1* var2), sizeof(byte)); for (int generatey = 0; generatey != var1; generatey++) {  for (int generatex = 0; generatex != var2; generatex++) {   ...(запись данных в массив)  } }

Похоже там не в malloc дело, каждый раз ошибка на разных индексах, получается время и свое и чужое потратил

Это как size_t(1000 * 1000)=4? gпо сути оно же 1000000 должно быть равно

Такого быть не может, если бы выделялось 4 байта, программа бы крашнулась еще быстрее, а там минимум 220000 выделяется судя по индексам переменных,+ только что проверил, в консоль 1000000 выводится при команде size_t(1000*1000)

А ещё, используя тип int вместо положенного size_t, вы не сможете работать с более чем 2 гигабайтами памяти, потому что в знаковые 4 байта бо́льшие индексы просто не влезут. А если переменные var1 и var2 тоже имеют тип int, то выражение var1* var2 может оказаться отрицательным числом из-за переполнения по той же самой причине

Но это к вопросу о «максимальном размере», а 1000000 в эти ограничения вполне вписывается

А ещё тип переменной array неизвестен, и за скромной фразой «запись данных в массив» вы спрятали кучу возможных ошибок, так что в общем ждём [mcve] чтобы не гадать (а то я вот уже успел не угадать один раз)

Там слишком много кода кидать придется + форматировать его, + вопрос был по теме того, есть ли у malloc/calloc ограничение по выделению блока

"слишком много кода кидать придется" - для вопроса следует локализовать проблему и соствить [mcve], а не вывалить в него весь свой код. Ну и если вопрос про ограничения malloc, то не стоило сюда пихать ошибку повреждения кучи, задавайте ее в отдельном вопросе.

Ограничение на размер выделяемого malloc/calloc задается реализацией стандартной библиотеки. Конкретно для vc++ оно обозначено макросом _HEAP_MAXREQ, который принимает значение 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0 на 64-битной системе, 0xFFFFFFE0 на 32-битной. То бишь на практике объем выделяемого блока ограничен только доступным свободным местом в оперативной памяти.

начала вылазить ошибка повреждения кучи

99% процентов, что она вызвана ошибками в коде.

Хочу поставить точку в этом вопросе, в целом malloc реально ограничивается только размерами оперативной памяти, однако что на счет моей проблемы, я перешел от malloc к new, сначала я попробовал разбить один большой массив на несколько маленьких, но ошибка все равно оставалась, потом решил использовать new и ошибка полностью пропала, причем это не первый раз когда такое случается, до этого заменял malloc на new и подобные ошибки с повреждением кучи пропадали, те кто наткнется на этот вопрос в будущем, лучше используйте new вместо malloc, по крайней мере он выглядит стабильнее.

@mrмава Это плохой совет. Прежде, чем пытаться устранять ошибку, надо было локализовать ее и определить причины появления. Если после перехода на new она пропала, то это значит, что стало только хуже. Ошибка в коде осталась, но явные проявления пропали, что только затруднит отладку.

Ошибка была не в коде, а в том что malloc как оказалось плохо выделяет память для кастомных типов данных, даже если все переменные в них имеют одинаковый размер

@mrмава что такое «плохо выделяет память»? Почему всех во всём мире работает хорошо, а вот конкретно у вас как-то «плохо»? В чём ваша уникальность? Почему вы вообще решили что что-то там «плохо»?
